# Can a count of a KGroupedTable be negative?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

My code is applying a groupBy on a KTable, followed by a count:

```
KStream<AggregationFields, Long> theCounts = theTable
            .groupBy((key, value) -> {
                AggregationFields af = new AggregationFields(
                        value.getUser(),
                        value.getGroup(),
                        value.getSegment);

                return KeyValue.pair(af, 1L);
            }, Serialized.with(AggregationFields.getSerde(), Serdes.Long()))
            .count()
            .toStream();
```

In my production environment I sometimes see the count producing negative numbers upon starting this application, even though I am using the app reset tool to make sure no internal topics are left over, as well as deleting any local stream state. Is there any circumstance where the count can be negative? Did I do it wrong?

I am on kafka-streams 1.0.1 (however, the server is running a pre-1.0 version, not sure if that matters).

Answer (score 1):

Each time, the base table is updated, Kafka Streams needs to send two record downstream to update the count, because in general, with multiple partitions, the two update record might be processed on different machines. One record is a "negative" subtraction record and the second is as "positive" addition record to the counts of potentially different keys.

If the update on the base table does not result in a key change for the count(), both records will be processed after each other and if the current count is zero, we would first decrease the count by one while processing the subtraction record and afterward increase the count again. For this special case, you might see a negative intermediate result.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, Matthias. In my case the negative numbers were not just transient, but it seems they were based on a bad Streams state. I will answer my own question below.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had my Streams app in a bad state, even though (I thought) I cleaned it up. Once I deployed it again with a new app ID, the counts looked good.